# Website first visit, how to detect?

Tags: php, web

I am doing a basic website where user has to enter the website and if it is the first visit, then he/she is shown some information. I do not want to use cookies since not all users are going to have their cookies enabled. The problem with IP, is that it is mostly dynamic, so not very effective either.

Also, are there are any libraries that I can use?

Comment: " where user has to enter the website and if it is the first entry, then he is shown some information" that is not understandable

Comment: I'd say use a combination of the given answers and the ideas you have. So do a check for IP, cookies and localStorage. If one of them is set then you know you don't have to re-present the information. Beware with IP addresses though. In some companies/schools alot of users have the same IP address when they're on the net.

Comment: Sorry, if it is not very clear. Basically when the user is entering the website for the first time, we need to detect it and show him information about the wesbite.

Comment: Generate a pretend cookie in the address as part of the query string, and then modify all your internal links to continue to use that same GUID. This isn't so popular now, since _everyone_ has at least session cookies enabled these days, even on mobile, but it'll do the trick reliably.

Answer (score 1):

IP doesn't identify a user. It simply identifies a node on the network (Firewall, NIC, etc). There is really no way to tell this globally without using cookies. You have to store something on their machine in order to make them return it to your application. Browsers are anonymous for security reasons. People have to volunteer something identifying.

The way I get around this issue is I log the user's interaction along with their session in MySQL. I check to see if they're using Javascript and if they have cookies enabled. If they have cookies enabled then I pass them a unique ID. If they don't then I just ignore the data. If they do have cookies or javascript turned on then I'll create additional flags in the DB. At the point they submit personally identifying info then I can pair their records with the rest of the information on file.

There is an old-skool way of doing this by passing $_GET vars via the [address] bar similar to Amazon. You could also make all of the buttons and links on the site use POST forms (but it's more of a pain). You can't trust the information though unless you hash the info and keep passing it forward. Always check the hashes to make sure they're not altering the query line.

So if you're passing a user ID, then you would have an address bar that could work something like this:

```
<?php
  function addrAppend($uid){
    //secret word would be something that you know so it works like a pre-shared key.
    $hash = md5($uid."secretword".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $app="?uid=$uid&hash=$hash";

    return $app;
  }

 ?>
```

Note that if you are hashing the IP address of the user and they're using a proxy this will fail. You can always hash their OS instead.

I hate doing this inline because it is not good form, but When you call it in the layout you could say:
       '>My Link

For the check and validation on the next page you could do something like:

```
      if(!empty($_GET['hash'])){
        if ($_GET['hash']==md5($temp_UID."secretword".$client_ADDR)){
         //then it's unaltered assuming they didn't guess your hashing convention
        } else {
         //then they altered the get vars so flush the info or end().
        }
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage for those with modern web browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build pro-level tracking solution. You can store following things from the user:

1. IP address
2. name of the operating system
3. screen resolution
4. time zone settings,
5. fonts installed on your computer,
6. the string with information about the browser (i.e. the User Agent String),
7. the time and date of the test,
8. plugins installed on your browser,
9. list of accepted MIME types,
10. the navigator object hashed, values of navigator.doNotTrack and navigator.buildID,
11. and the generated identifier.

Ofcourse, you won't need all of these. A subset of these (like `IP`, `Screen resolution`, `UserAgent`) as fingerprint for the user is good enough.

**How I know?**
Worked with `Cross browser fingerprinting` technology earlier. You can read more, here:
http://fingerprint.pet-portal.eu/

Infact you can track actual-entry-vs-returning user, even if he changes the browser!

Comment: Screen resolution can change if someone's using a VM. Also on mobile devices when they flip you'd need to make sure you were catching the flip. If someone alters headers or is using a proxy [IP change] then you would have differing info on the following page.

Answer (score -1):

IP is the best way to identify a user. It CAN change obviously, but that's the way it is really.

Comment: IP isn't the best way. Multiple users can have same ip or a user can have multiple ips. A user authentication system is more accurate.

Comment: Many users can be behind a NAT router with the same external IP. So IP is not the best user fingerprint if used alone.